# How to find first matching object in array of objects with emails array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have array of accounts. Every account has id, name, and array of emails.
I want to find first matching object where `account.email === this.userEmail` so I tried :

```
this.accounts.find(account => account.emails.find(email => email === this.userEmail));
```

but it doesnt work.

How to find first matching account?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it not return anything at all? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What is the expected and actual behavior?

Comment: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inner `find` you are returning a boolean. You could do it like this:

```
this.accounts.find(account => 
  account.emails.some(email => email === this.userEmail)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
this.accounts.find(account => account.emails.some(email => email === this.userEmail));
```

Use Array.some